# Angular material radio button in a material expansion panel disappear on scroll in iOS 13

Tags: ios, scroll, angular-material, radio-button, accordion

I have an `accordion` with some radio buttons that only show up on first refresh and only if they are being shown on the screen at time of refresh. That means, on page refresh or when collapsing and expanding the items, those will be fine. But scrolling you will have items not being rendered. Collapse one and the items being shown on screen at that moment will be rendered, but all the rest will have the problem (including the ones that were originally being shown).

This bug only happens on iOS 13+ (Safari or Chrome, doesn't matter) and doesn't happen on Android (any browser), iOS until 12.x.x, Chrome desktop or even Safari on a Mac computer (other bugs happen, but not this one). It also happens on iOS Safari in desktop mode, so I know it isn't related to the responsive code, but related to how iOS renders the component regardless of mode.

Also, it is still functional, which means it might just be transparent for some reason.

I looked for vendor CSS prefixes and found none in the classes being used here, so all CSS should hopefully work correctly in any browser (removed classes from the code below for clarity).

- Just after refresh:

[image: IMAGEM 1]

- Other Items that were not visible at refresh time (note that the V / ^ icon also disappears):

[image: IMAGEM 2]

My code right now looks like the following. It seems to be an oddly specific bug, so I will try to keep this code as close to the real thing as possible.

Almost all items in columns also have a `matTooltip`, including the radio button

```html
<mat-accordion multi="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel expanded *ngFor="let item of items">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                <h3>
                    {{item.name}}
                </h3>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        {{item.code}}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        Level {{item.level}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
            <div *ngIf="item.subitems.length > 0; then withSubItems else withoutSubItems"></div>
            <ng-template #withSubItems>
                <div>
                    <caption>
                        Select One
                    </caption> 
                    <mat-radio-group>
                        <table mat-table [dataSource]="item.subitems">
                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns" style="display: none;"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let subitems; columns: columns"></tr>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="radioButton">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                    Sub-item
                                </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let subitem">
                                    <mat-radio-button value="{{subitem.code}}"
                                            [disabled]="shouldBeDisabled(subitem)"
                                            [checked]="subitem.isChecked"
                                            (click)="add(item, subitem, 'T')">
                                        <div>
                                            {{subitem.code}}
                                        </div>
                                    </mat-radio-button>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="info1">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                    Info 1
                                </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let subitem">
                                    <span>
                                        {{subitem.info1}}
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="info2">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                                    Info 2
                                </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let subitem">
                                    <span>
                                        {{subitem.info2}}
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <!-- etc. -->
                        </table>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #withoutSubItems>
                <div>
                    There aren't any sub-items
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

This has been quite annoying as I don't have an iOS device for debugging, so I'm being forced to deploy changes in test environment for asking for a tester to check if it solved the problem.

If it helps, this component originally had an ordinary HTML table and radio buttons. At this point, the problem was happening to the title. I decided then to rewrite it. This time using `mat-panel-title` that wasn't being used and used the time to also work on the table, transforming it into a `row` `col` kind of table from bootstrap.

This solved the problem for the title, but it moved to the whole table. So I decided to rewrite the table again and transformed it into a `mat-table`. It did help, but now the radio button still has the problem. But unfortunately this time rewriting the radio button into a material radio button didn't work.

The v / ^ icon had the problem since the beginning and none of the refactorings affected it.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to have access to a few other iOS devices on different iOS versions. This seems to occur only on devices running iOS 13^. Does anybody know of changes made to iOS webkit that could be causing this starting from iOS 13?